# Haskell: parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets) with list comprehension

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and am trying to write a simple list comprehension and assign it to a variable. Here is my `haskell.hs` file:

```
--find all multiples of 3 and 5 under 1000
multiples :: [Int]
let multiples = [x | x <- [1..1000], (x `mod` 5 == 0) || (x `mod` 3 == 0)]
```

then when I try to compile the program with `ghc haskell.hs` I get the following error:

```
haskell.hs:12:1:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

Regards!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have an extra `let`. It should be:

```
multiples :: [Int]
multiples = [x | x <- [1..1000], (x `mod` 5 == 0) || (x `mod` 3 == 0)]
```

This isn't OCaml, so you don't need `let` at the top level.

This might be a little confusing because older versions of GHCi required a `let` for defining names. However, this was just a quirk of the interpreter and isn't needed any more with modern GHC versions.

Comment: aha! Thanks for this. The compiler certainly isn't forgiving though! :(